# Java convert object to StringArray and iterate the array to print values

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, collections

I have a POJO as follows:

```
public class TestDto{
  private String columnA;
  private String columnB;
  private String columnC;
  private String columnD;
  ...//...//
}
```

DB returns me a list of TestDto;

```
List<TestDto> dto = //resultsList from DB.;
```

The parameters in TestDto may be columnA,columnB,columnC,columnD,......columnCE,columnCF....it's dynamic.

I want to convert list of TestDto to list of String array using lambda and then iterate the list and string array and assign the values to cell in excel.

I tried below but this didnt work.

```
List<String> stringList = dto.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());

for(int i=0; i<stringList.size(); i++)
{
   System.out.println("stringlist..."+stringList.get(i));
}
```

The output that gets printed is `TestDto` object but not `string[]`.
I want to convert `List<TestDto>` to `List<String[]>` and then do the foll.

```
List<TestDto> listTestDto =...;
String[] stringArray = null;
    
    for(int i=0; i<listTestDto.size(); i++)
    {
     stringArray = listTestDto.get(i);
     for(int j=0; j< stringArray.length; j++){
     System.out.println("stringArray - "+stringArray[i]);
     }
    }
```

Data:
List:

```
columnA:1, columnB:ABC, columnC: 11111, columnD :null.....
columnA:2, columnB:DEF, columnC: 22222, columnD :null.....
columnA:3, columnB:GHI, columnC: 33333, columnD :null.......
columnA:4, columnB:JKL, columnC: 44444, columnD :null......
```

Output:

```
stringArray - 1
stringArray - ABC
stringArray - 11111
stringArray - null
stringArray - 2
stringArray - DEF
stringArray - 22222
stringArray - null
stringArray - 3
stringArray - GHI
stringArray - 33333
stringArray - null
stringArray - 4
stringArray - JKL
stringArray - 44444
stringArray - null
```

USeCase:

```
1. output is List<TestDto>
2. output is List<Object[]>
```

Comment: `TestDto may be ... dynamic`  What does this mean?  Java doesn't have 'dynamic" objects, the fields have to be fixed.  You should explain better what you are doing.

Comment: If TestDto can be dynamic (an interface I guess), probably you have to use reflection to retrieve the values in the map part (Object::toString)

Comment: I have made and edit to my question where 1 use case is return type List<TestDto> and another with List<Object[]>. I want to have a solution common for both.

Answer (score 1):

**You need a transformer method `toStringArray` for `TestDto`**

Add `toStringArray` method to TestDto

```
public class TestDto {
    private String columnA;
    private String columnB;
    private String columnC;
    private String columnD;
    ...//...//
    
    public String[] toStringArray() {
        return new String[] { columnA, columnB, columnC, columnD,... };
    }
}
```

Use `map` operator from `stream` and pass transformer method reference

```
List<String[]> output = list.stream().map(TestDto::toStringArray).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Test your output

```
// Test output
for (int i = 0; i < output.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(op.get(i)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `TestDto` has *dynamic* fields, that is, its structure is undefined, and the entire TestDto can be represented as a map `Map<String, String>`.

Therefore, the list of `TestDto` is changed into the list of maps `List<Map<String, String>>`, which can be transformed into `List<String[]>` where each string array stores map values:

```java
List<Map<String, String>> listTestDto =...; // 

List<String[]> strings = listTestDto
    .stream() // Stream<Map<String, String>>
    .map(Map::values) // Stream<Collection<String>>
    .map(v -> v.toArray(new String[0]))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```